# why when publish to Azure Website Double the size storage with the obj folder inside

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

when publishing to the Azure web site from visual studio site size 400MB I see in the azure portal that my site is almost 800MB...

I search all sub folders and I realize that inside the obj\Release\Package there is "PackageTmp" which contain the all site with all my folders (some of them big files for download).

The question is why asp.net need the site twice ?
can i simply remove the obj folder with ftp app and the site will be ok ?

I Need more size it's not fair to scale becuase of that...

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy from Visual Studio, you are using msdeploy. Normally, that should not be copying `obj\Release\Package` to the Azure Web App.

To check what's in your Azure Web App, it's best to use [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console). In there, go to your `D:\home\site\wwwroot` folder, and check what files are there. Are you really seeing an `obj\Release\Package` folder in there (i.e. D:\home\site\wwwroot\obj\Release\Package`)?

If that's not where you see it, please provide more details:

- what version of VS?
- what type of app are you deploying (e.g. is it an MVC app)?
- are you deploying debug or retails?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your answer and advising the Kudu Console. I prefer to use FileZilla. And Yes I see the obj\Release\Package inside the site. By mistake I start new mvc site and then removed the mvc lib + folders... The vs is 2013 ultimate. how can i know about deploing debug or retail ?

Comment: It's one of the options under 'Settings' when you publish from Visual Studio using msdeploy.

Comment: I found under project properties in package/publish web tab the option to set configuration debug/release which i understand that i have to choose the release. I hope it's solve the problem. thanks...

Comment: Tested few times and always getting this error on publish: Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy detected insufficient space on disk.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE.)

Comment: That just means you don't have enough space in your site. It's not a sign of any particular error. Note that if you have multiple free sites in the same region, they all share the same 1GB limit. That may be what you're seeing.

Comment: I got 3 shared sites and in all of them I see The file system storage 1023MB. THANK YOU !!!